# How to create a unit test for a class which uses a trait?

Tags: 8, testing

Simple as this:

```
class A {
  use StringTranslationTrait;
  
  public function something() {
    $b = 1+2;
    $this->t($b);
    return $b;
  }
}
```

I would like to unit test the `something()` method, but I can't since the `StringTranslation` trait uses a static container call:

```
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException: \Drupal::$containe is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container.
```

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StringTranslationTrait also has a setStringTranslation() method so you can inject a string translation mock for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Could you update or link to an example, please?

Answer (score 10):

Following on Bedir's answer, here is an example.

I have a test that is using the class DurationService. DurationService uses the StringTranslationTrait as follows:

```
class DurationService implements DurationServiceInterface {
  use StringTranslationTrait;
  ...
```

To test this, I am doing the following (note, using a class that extends UnitTestCase):

```
$duration_service = new DurationService();
$duration_service->setStringTranslation($this->getStringTranslationStub());
```

This calls [StringTranslationTrait::setStringTranslation()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/function/StringTranslationTrait%3A%3AsetStringTranslation/8.2.x) passing it the response from [UnitTestCase::getStringTranslationStub()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21Tests%21UnitTestCase.php/function/UnitTestCase%3A%3AgetStringTranslationStub/8.2.x).

Comment: Thank you for the example. Good extension for Berdir's answer.

Comment: For reference, note that you need to use $this->t() and not just t().

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it, note your test must extend Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $container = new ContainerBuilder();
    \Drupal::setContainer($container);
    $container->set('string_translation', self::getStringTranslationStub());
  }
```

Comment: I feel this an unnecessary  extra step:
Your class has the "setStringTranslation" method, that is just one call. Also don't forget you don't have a valid container and services in a "pure" unittest.

Comment: Interesting, as I got this from looking at Unit tests in core.

Answer (score 0):

By implementing the ContainerFactoryPluginInterface you can use dependency injection to fake the string translation service.

```
class A implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface { 
  use StringTranslationTrait; 

  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, TranslationInterface $string_translation);
    $this->stringTranslation =$string_translation;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $container->get('string_translation'));
  }

  public function something() { 
    $b = 1+2; 
    $this->t($b); 
    return $b; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree to implement something in your unit just to able test it.

Comment: This is what the Drupal documentation recommends.

Comment: Can you please attach then a link in your answer?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/agile-unit-testing

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21tests%21src%21Unit%21CommentLinkBuilderTest.php/class/CommentLinkBuilderTest/8.2.x

Comment: Read both links: It states nowhere, that it's a good general approach, when you are using a trait (like StringTranslation) it would be a good approach to implement ContainerFactoryPLuginInterface.

In the original question I state nowhere that am only interested in plugin classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the [FormValidatorTest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21Tests%21Core%21Form%21FormValidatorTest.php/class/FormValidatorTest/8.5.x):

For the class

```
/**
 * Provides validation of form submissions.
 */
class FormValidator implements FormValidatorInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack, TranslationInterface $string_translation, CsrfTokenGenerator $csrf_token, LoggerInterface $logger, FormErrorHandlerInterface $form_error_handler) {
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
    $this->stringTranslation = $string_translation;
    $this->csrfToken = $csrf_token;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->formErrorHandler = $form_error_handler;
  }
```

This is the test

```
  /**
   * Tests the 'validation_complete' $form_state flag.
   *
   * @covers ::validateForm
   * @covers ::finalizeValidation
   */
  public function testValidationComplete() {
    $form_validator = $this->getMockBuilder('Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator')
      ->setConstructorArgs([new RequestStack(), $this->getStringTranslationStub(), $this->csrfToken, $this->logger, $this->formErrorHandler])
      ->setMethods(NULL)
      ->getMock();

    $form = [];
    $form_state = new FormState();
    $this->assertFalse($form_state->isValidationComplete());
    $form_validator->validateForm('test_form_id', $form, $form_state);
    $this->assertTrue($form_state->isValidationComplete());
  }
```

You can use as constructor param `$this->getStringTranslationStub()`

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question: I don't have string translation argument in my constructor.

Comment: @ssibal. I see, I misread the question.