# Call to undefined function t() in an Unit test

Tags: 8, testing

I'm trying to test a method from the [dev](https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/onlyone-8.x-1.x-dev.zip) version of the [Allow a content type only once (Only One)](https://www.drupal.org/project/onlyone) module that have a `t()` call inside:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\onlyone\Utility;

class InternalFunctions {


  public static function getLanguageLabel($language) {
    switch ($language) {
      case 'und':
      case '':
        // If the language is empty then is Undetermined.
        return t('Not specified');

      case 'zxx':
        return t('Not applicable');

      default:
        return ucfirst($language);
    }
  }

}
```

With the following Unit test:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Tests\onlyone\Unit;

use Drupal\onlyone\Utility\InternalFunctions;
use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;


class InternalFunctionsTest extends UnitTestCase {


  public function testGetLanguageLabel($language_code, $expected) {
    $this->assertEquals($expected, InternalFunctions::getLanguageLabel($language_code));
  }

  public function providerGetLanguageLabel() {
    $tests[] = ['', 'Not specified'];
    $tests[] = ['und', 'Not specified'];
    $tests[] = ['zxx', 'Not applicable'];
    $tests[] = ['es', 'Es'];
    $tests[] = ['en', 'En'];

    return $tests;
  }
}
```

and when I run the test I receive these errors:

```
1) Drupal\Tests\onlyone\Unit\InternalFunctionsTest::testGetLanguageLabel with data set #0 ('', 'Not specified')
Error: Call to undefined function Drupal\onlyone\Utility\t()

/Users/adriancid/Sites/drupal84-test/modules/drupal.org/onlyone/src/Utility/InternalFunctions.php:26
/Users/adriancid/Sites/drupal84-test/modules/drupal.org/onlyone/tests/src/Unit/InternalFunctionsTest.php:30

2) Drupal\Tests\onlyone\Unit\InternalFunctionsTest::testGetLanguageLabel with data set #1 ('und', 'Not specified')
Error: Call to undefined function Drupal\onlyone\Utility\t()

/Users/adriancid/Sites/drupal84-test/modules/drupal.org/onlyone/src/Utility/InternalFunctions.php:26
/Users/adriancid/Sites/drupal84-test/modules/drupal.org/onlyone/tests/src/Unit/InternalFunctionsTest.php:30

3) Drupal\Tests\onlyone\Unit\InternalFunctionsTest::testGetLanguageLabel with data set #2 ('zxx', 'Not applicable')
Error: Call to undefined function Drupal\onlyone\Utility\t()
```

But the `t()` function is always defined inside Drupal. If I remove the `t()` calls inside the method the test works fine.

I found in [Unit testing more complicated Drupal classes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/phpunit/unit-testing-more-complicated-drupal-classes) that:

> ... global functions do not exist in the testing environment.

And a method to made this works, but I find that this is complicate things just to use a test and method with the `t()` function inside.

So, there is not a simple method to test a class method that have a `t()` call inside?

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, but you can create a shadow function in your test namespace to define `t()`.  `TimeTest` in core does something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@mpdonadio](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpdonadio) I have one way to solve this:

In the test file you need to add a namespace with the same namespace where is the method that you're trying to test and then define the function.

```
namespace Drupal\onlyone\Utility;

/**
 * Shadow t() system call.
 *
 * @param string $string
 *   A string containing the English text to translate.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function t($string) {
  return $string;
}
```

Maybe there are another method because I'm still wondering how is possible that in the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module a test named [testToString()](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/tests/src/Unit/Utility/WebformArrayHelperTest.php#n31) don't use this approach and works for a method with a `t()` call inside: [WebformArrayHelper::toString()](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/Utility/WebformArrayHelper.php#n22).

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using t() inside classes. The string translation trait should be included instead (if it is not already part of a parent class). Then you will use:

```
$this->t()
```

Then you can use the answer I provided here as to how to do unit tests with string translation trait: [How to unit test a class which uses a trait?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220636/how-to-unit-test-a-class-which-uses-a-trait/233286#233286)

Comment: The method is static I can't use $this inside.

Comment: Ahh I missed that. Then the method you found is the correct way to go about it.

Comment: I think that you should keep your answer here as a guide. Please don't remove it.