# How to shadow a core function used in two different tests files?

Tags: 8, testing

I have two tests files with tests that need to [shadow the t() function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/257631/28275) in the [Node Revision Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete) project, one test file is placed in:

[tests/src/Unit/Utility/TimeTest.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/node_revision_delete/tree/tests/src/Unit/Utility/TimeTest.php?h=8.x-1.x)

And the other in:

[tests/src/Unit/NodeRevisionDeleteTest.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/node_revision_delete/tree/tests/src/Unit/NodeRevisionDeleteTest.php?h=8.x-1.x)

At this time I shadow the `t()` function with the same code at the end of each test file because the `t()` function is needed to run tests in both files.

```
namespace Drupal\node_revision_delete\Utility;

/**
 * Shadow t() system call.
 *
 * @param string $string
 *   A string containing the English text to translate.
 *
 * @return string
 *   The translated string.
 */
function t($string) {
  return $string;
}
```

When I run each test file all is working fine, but when I run all the project tests I get an error as I have declared the `t()` function twice:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare
>   Drupal\node_revision_delete\Utility\t() (previously declared in
>   /Users/adriancid/Sites/drupal84-test/modules/drupal.org/node_revision_delete/tests/src/Unit/NodeRevisionDeleteTest.php:357)
>   in
>   /Users/adriancid/Sites/drupal84-test/modules/drupal.org/node_revision_delete/tests/src/Unit/Utility/TimeTest.php
>   on line 195

The only way that I found to make these works is to pass the tests that need the `t()` function from one test file to the other, but doing this I will have a mix of tests from diferent classes and I won't be able to use the `@covers` section in the test definition.

So, what is the correct way to shadow a core function used in two different tests files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in a !function_exists()

See core/tests/Drupal/Tests/Core/Render/Element/MachineNameTest.php for example:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Core\Render\Element;

if (!function_exists('t')) {

  function t($string, array $args = []) {
    return strtr($string, $args);
  }

}
```

That said, t() as a specific example is deprecated and should not be used in classes, use the StringTranslationTrait/service instead and you can actually inject it.

Comment: Hi @Berdir, thanks for your answer, I use the t() function because it is used in a static method in a Utility function. I tried your solution but it doesn't work, can you check the patch here? https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete/issues/2991388#comment-12721884

Comment: Its weird, the test works on drupal.org but not in my local environment, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: drupal.org runs tests through run-tests.sh, which spawns a separate process for each test. Sounds like your utility classs then maybe shouldn't be static because you have dependencies to services? unit-testability is one of the reasons you want to create services and use DI instead of static methods. You're fixing the wrong problem :)

Comment: I don't have dependencies on services, you can check the code at https://cgit.drupalcode.org/node_revision_delete/tree/src/Utility/Time.php I posted a question related to Utility class and Services on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/251111/28275 and it seems that I can keep my method as static, I don't know what do you think about this.

Comment: Yes, you do. t() is just a wrapper around creating a new TranslatableMarkup() object, which in turn uses the string_translation service.  You *have* dependencies, they're just hidden behind a function.